# How to use bash variable prefixes under sh, ksh, csh

Tags: bash, variables, ksh

I have **bash** script which checks presence of certain files and that the content has a valid format. It uses variable prefixes so i can easily add/remove new files w/o the need of further adjustments.

Problem is that i need to run this on AIX servers where bash is not present. I've adjusted the script except the part with variable prefixes. After some attempts i am lost and have no idea how to properly migrate the following piece of code so it runs under sh ( `$(echo ${!ifile_@})` ). Alternatively i have **ksh** or **csh** if plain **sh** is not an option.

Thank you in advance for any help/hints

```
#!/bin/sh
# Source files
ifile_one="/path/to/file/one.csv"
ifile_two="/path/to/file/two.csv"
ifile_three="/path/to/file/three.csv"
ifile_five="/path/to/file/four.csv"

min_columns='10'
existing_files=""
nonexisting_files=""
valid_files=""
invalid_files=""

# Check that defined input-files exists and can be read.
for input_file in $(echo ${!ifile_@})
do
    if [ -r ${!input_file} ]; then
        existing_files+="${!input_file} "
    else
        nonexisting_files+="${!input_file} "
    fi
done
echo "$existing_files"
echo "$nonexisting_files"

# Check that defined input files have proper number of columns. 
for input_file_a in $(echo "$existing_files")
do
    check=$(grep -v "^$" $input_file_a | sed 's/[^;]//g' | awk -v min_columns="$min_columns" '{ if (length == min_columns) {print "OK"} else {print "KO"} }' | grep -i KO)
    if [ ! -z "$check" ]; then
        invalid_files+="${input_file_a} "
    else
        valid_files+="${input_file_a} "
    fi
done
echo "$invalid_files"
echo "$valid_files"
```

Bash returns expected output (of the four ECHOes):

```
/path/to/file/one.csv /path/to/file/two.csv /path/to/file/three.csv
/path/to/file/four.csv

/path/to/file/three.csv
/path/to/file/one.csv /path/to/file/two.csv
```

ksh/sh throws:

```
./report.sh[14]: "${!ifile_@}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
```

Comment: You could use ksh arrays instead of the prefix parameter expansion.

Comment: In Aix, `/bin/ksh` doesn't support this, but `/bin/ksh93` does.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thanks, tried that but it returns following as a content of "valid_files":
`input_file input_file input_file input_file input_file input_file`

Comment: Ok, another idea: `set | grep '^ifile_' | while IFS='=' read V W; do printf "$V = $W\n"; done`

Comment: @Hakun1n : I think it is unnecessarily painful to convert a bash program to sh, unless it really uses only simple shell facilities which are also present in sh. I also wouldn't use `csh`, because programming in csh is also rather unpleasant. Hence i would rewrite it in ksh93. Think about "rewriting", not "converting", and you will have an easier life. Yet another possibility would be to write everything in i.e. Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Benjamin W. and @user1934428 , ksh93 arrays are the answer.
So bellow code works for me as desired.

```
#!/bin/ksh93
typeset -A ifile
ifile[one]="/path/to/file/one.csv"
ifile[two]="/path/to/file/two.csv"
ifile[three]="/path/to/file/three.csv"
ifile[whatever]="/path/to/file/something.csv"

existing_files=""
nonexisting_files=""

for input_file in "${!ifile[@]}"
do
    if [ -r ${ifile[$input_file]} ]; then
        existing_files+="${ifile[$input_file]} "
    else
        nonexisting_files+="${ifile[$input_file]} "
    fi
done
```